# Parsing a file and creating histogram with python

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have to create an histogram from a source file that I have to parse:

```
for line in fp:
        data =  line.split('__')
        if(len(data)==3 and data[2]!='\n' and data[1]!=''):
            job_info = data[0].split(';')
            [...]
            job_times_req = data[2].split(';')
                if(len(job_times_req)==6):
                    cpu_req = job_times_req[3]
```

The parsing is correct, I have try it, but now I would like to create an histogram on how many time I have called the X cpu. Example if I have called the first one 10 times, the second 4 times and so on I would like to see the hist of this.

I have try something like:

```
a.append(cpu_req )
plt.hist(a, 100)
plt.xlabel('CPU N°', fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel('Number of calls', fontsize= 20)
plt.show()
```

but is not working, how can I store the data in the correct way to show them in a histogram?

Solved with a simple cast

```
a.append(int(cpu_req))
```

Comment: If you solved it your self, please post the solution as an answer rather than editing your question.

Comment: I can't too low rating. Thanks for the suggestion